# Version Control for SSMS 2016

Tags: t-sql, version-control

**Version Control for SQL projects - I'd like to explore what would be your opinion and possible solution for the following:**

We have a group of SQL developers. Everyone has SSMS 2016 installed. Not everyone has Visual Studio installed on their machine (or is allowed to install). The only approved version control is TFS (because that's what the .NET developers were allowed to use). All SQL developers work on the same project and constantly overwriting the production file(s) version on the network share. This (obviously) is a source of frustration due to may unintentional code overwrites - therefore source control is needed.

I do not see TFS available within SSMS anymore and suggested 'hacks' how to re-enable it are not working for me as I would expect. What clean, straight forward options do we have?

Comment: The question and the tag are mismatched IMO.

Comment: can you suggest a better one ? I'll re-label. The idea was to ask tSQL crowd since they should/may have or know some functional version control solutions.

Comment: Is [this  link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/11/21/source-control-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/) of any help?

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35935593/243373)?

Comment: Thanks TT, these are the posts I was indirectly referring to. The 1st one is a 'hack' and together with the second one both are using Visual Studio which we cannot use. Also the TFS (when integrated into the Win explorer) seems to show up only under Admin permissions which no one from the dev team has.